# Is it possible to set a default theme at compile time for DaisyUI (Tailwind)?

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

DaisyUI has [default themes](https://v1.daisyui.com/docs/default-themes) and you can change them with the `data-theme` attribute e.g. `<html data-theme="cupcake">`. It seems as though the default is the `light` theme.

The problem is that I want to be able to use the `@apply` directive with DaisyUI so that I can have BEM class names in the template and DaisyUI utility classes in the style block. It seems that I can't set a default that will be picked up at compile time.

In my `tailwind.config` I've tried using the `light` theme to see if I could overwrite it, e.g.:

```
  plugins: [require('daisyui')],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        light: {
          primary: '#EF3054',
          secondary: '#C67F43',
          accent: '#43AA8B',
          neutral: '#FBF5F3',
          base100: '#FFFFFF',
          info: '#3ABFF8',
          success: '#36D399',
          warning: '#FBBD23',
          error: '#F87272',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried looking into the library itself for clues into how I could overwrite the default theme at compile time but I can't see how.

Although some people consider BEM with Tailwind an anti-pattern, I had long held this view myself as well, I have since changed my mind and feel that the extra effort does help disambiguate your template with the added benefit of allowing bespoke CSS whenever you need to drop into it so please don't suggest just using the inline utility classes as I know this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your issue exactly.
But once you changed tailwind config, then it should work.
If you want to change your default theme with another one, it requires some code.

But now you changed your light theme, so it will directly work.

Please check your `content` property again. I'm working on Next JS.

And I think `base100` property should be `base-100`.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  ...
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        light: {
          ...require("daisyui/src/colors/themes")["[data-theme=light]"],
          primary: '#EF3054',
          secondary: '#C67F43',
          accent: '#43AA8B',
          neutral: '#FBF5F3',
          "base-100": '#FFFFFF',
          info: '#3ABFF8',
          success: '#36D399',
          warning: '#FBBD23',
          error: '#F87272',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
  ...
```